# using Case get values from different table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i need results based on a condition with out using dynamic sql

like when `@param1=10` 
then i need all rows details from table1

else i need details from table2

i had tried something like below but it does not give the result

```
declare @param1 int=10;
select * from 

case when @param1=10 then table1

else table2 end
```

Note : i know i can use if condition like below

```
if @param1=10 
select * from table1
else
select * from table2
```

but in my case the query is very lengthy so i don't want to replace all query once again

so i hope i can just do something with case with out replacing all query again.

please help me to solve the problem

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @wewesthemenace thanks for your quick replay . is there any ways other than dynamic sql ?

Comment: There is, but that may lead to performance problem.

Comment: Do both of the tables have the same column definitions? Because if not, this isn't going to work without dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes both table has same column definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a `UNION ALL` as a subquery, and then build the rest of your query around that:

```
SELECT
    * --TODO - Columns
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE @Param=10
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE @Param<>10) t
WHERE /* other conditions here */
```

---

As an aside - if you have two tables that contain the same "types" of rows, such that you're wanting to interchange them in queries, it may be an indication that your data model is broken - what should have been modelled as a attribute has instead become embedded in your table *names*. E.g. rather than having `FemaleEmployees` and `MaleEmployees` tables, it ought to be a single `Employees` table with a `Gender` column.

Comment: here it is a one line statement but in my case the select statement itself contain more than 200 lines so can i repeat the select condition again ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV - I don't understand - you could take the query I've provided in my answer and just edit the two areas with comments, and you wouldn't be repeating anything.

Comment: unfortunately i have a long query . i mean select (long sequence) from table where condition . so i need to repeat the select two times ??

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV - no, you can put the long sequence where I've marked `--TODO - Columns` and just retain the `select *` within the subquery.

Comment: yes now i got it...thanks for your answer..but what about performance??

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV - first, set performance *goals*. Then, write clear code that does the job. With both of those done, *measure* the performance. If it meets the goals, move onto your next job. Don't attempt to achieve good performance by guessing or learning "rules of thumb". If it doesn't perform adequately, you need to isolate where the performance issue is.

Answer (score 0):

One option to avoid dynamic SQL is a `union`:

```
select * from table1 where @param1 = 10
union all
select * from table2 where @param1 <> 10
```

Comment: This will work if table1 and table2 have the same columns. It is always wise to state the columns that you want to retrieve anyway instead of using the asterix (*)

Comment: yes i agree with you but it also need to repeat the code again . i am trying to avoid repeating the code

Answer (score 0):

If both the tables have some unique id to join, you can use something like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @param1 = 10 then t1.C1
ELSE t2.C1
END as C
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on 
t1.Id = t2.Id
```

try this, but you need to check the performance of your query..

```
Declare @t1 Table(id int , Name nvarchar(MAX))
Declare @t2 Table(id int , Name nvarchar(MAX))
Declare @t int = 10

insert into @t1 values (1,'Jhon')
insert into @t1 values (2, 'Jhon2')

insert into @t2 values (3, 'Rahul')
insert into @t2 values (4, 'Rahul2')

Select distinct Case when @t = 10 then t1.Name else t2.Name end as Name
from @t1 t1 cross join @t2 t2
```

another approach

```
with CTE_t1 as (Select * from table1 where @param1 = 10), 
    CTE_t2 as (Select * from table2 where @param1 != 10),
    CTE_t3 as (Select * from CTE_t1 union all Select * from CTE_t2)

    Select * -- you can use your 200 line of code here only once
    from CTE_t3
```

Comment: table1 and table2 has same column definitions but there is no common data between these tables. in some case the data will be in table one and in another case data will be in table2

Comment: I think CTE will be best fit in your scenario